Clarifying the Maximum Principle for Perturbed Solutions
The idea of this problem is to consider $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ such that
$$
- \Delta u + x \cdot \nabla u \leq 0 \quad \text{in } \Omega.
$$
We aim to prove that
$$
\max_{\overline{\Omega}} u = \max_{\partial \Omega} u.
$$
I have already proved the case for the strong inequality, and for the general case, the exercise suggests finding an appropriate $\lambda > 0$ for $w(x) = u(x) + \varepsilon e^{\lambda x_1}$. What I did was assume $\lambda = \max_{\overline{\Omega}} |x|$. With this choice, we have
$$
- \Delta w + x \cdot \nabla w < 0.
$$
My argument was as follows:
$$
\max_{\overline{\Omega}} \left(u + \varepsilon e^{\lambda x_1}\right) = \max_{\partial \Omega} \left(u + \varepsilon e^{\lambda x_1}\right) \implies \max_{\overline{\Omega}} u = \max_{\partial \Omega} u,  
$$
by letting $\varepsilon \to 0$.
However, upon closer inspection, I think that the limit $\varepsilon \to 0$ may not necessarily hold true.

What makes you think the last equality does not hold in the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$ ?

@K.defaoite I don't see why the point will stay on the border, and in other exercises I solved before there is some way to play with the max function to explicity proof that the point will be in the border.

It was very simple.
$$
\max_{\bar{\Omega}}u(x) + \varepsilon e^{\lambda_1 x_1} \leq \max_{\partial\Omega} u(x) + \varepsilon \max_{\partial \Omega}e^{\lambda_1x_1}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow u(x) + \varepsilon e^{\lambda_1x_1} \leq \max_{\partial\Omega} u(x) + \varepsilon \max_{\partial \Omega}e^{\lambda_1x_1}
$$
Now is safe to do the limit.
